# Reduce and centralize TextFields

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to **reduce the size (width and height)** of these two TextFields and **align it to the center of the screen.** I tried using Container() and Center() but there's always a problem with where I'm trying to put it.

```
class _TelaPrincipalState extends State<TelaPrincipal> {
  final firstTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final secondTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: firstTextEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Insert first input',
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: secondTextEditingController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Insert second input',
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              ),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`, to center Column Widgets

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My App'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: firstTextEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Insert first input',
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: secondTextEditingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Insert second input',
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Omar Mahmoud! It completely solved the problem! I just have one more question, is there a way to increase the height (line height) of the TextFields? I'm kinda new in Flutter.

Comment: what do you mean by line hight

Comment: I mean the "vertical padding" of it. The vertical size inside the TextField. In other words, the vertical size of the white portion of the TextField (pretty much the height of it)

Comment: you need to increase   contentPadding

Answer (score 1):

Set the main axis alignment of the column to center.It will work.

```
return Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
);
```